# Using the digits $1$, $2$, $3$, $7$, $8$, $9$, and $0$, how many $4$-digit numbers can be created that are greater than $3718$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Using the digits $1$, $2$, $3$, $7$, $8$, $9$, and $0$, how many $4$-digit numbers can be created that are greater than $3718$?

My answer is : $(360)(1)(12)(40)= 413$

Comment: How did you get your answer? What is your thought process?

Comment: To make sure: Can digits be used repeatedly?

Comment: With those digits, how many $4$-digit numbers can be created that are greater than $3000$? (I wouldn't expent the answers to be the same, because you can create some numbers between $3000$ and $3718,$ for instance $3298.$)

Comment: Did you mean $360 + 1 + 12 + 40 = 413$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event that digits are not allowed to be repeated:

Let us break this into cases:
 - Case 1: The number is greater than or equal to $4000$

- Step 1: Pick the first digit.  Options are $7,8,9$ for a total of $3$ options

  - Step 2: Pick the second digit.  Options are any of $1,2,3,7,8,9,0$ except what was picked in step 1 for a total of $6$ options.
  - Step 3: Pick the third digit.  Options are any of the available digits except those already picked for a total of $5$ options.
  - Step 4: Pick the fourth digit.  Options are any of the available digits except those already picked for a total of $4$ options.
  - This gives a total of $3\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4$ numbers in this case
- Case 2: The number is less than $4000$

  - Case 2a: The number starts with $371\square$.  There is only one possibility: $3719$
  - Case 2b: The number starts with $37\square\square$ and the third digit is larger than $1$.  There are $3\cdot 4$ possibilities here
  - Case 2c: The number starts with $3\square\square\square$ and the second digit is larger than $7$.  There are $2\cdot 5\cdot 4$ possibilities.

This gives a final grand total of $3\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4 + 1 + 3\cdot 4 + 2\cdot 5\cdot 4=413$ numbers.

Your mistake was that the number you counted was instead the number of numbers greater than $3000$ that use the available digits, but *not* the number of numbers greater than $3718$.  There are numbers that you counted between $3000$ and $3718$ that you shouldn't have.

Comment: I got it thanks for helping me out